# Oklahoma: Can I still vote in person if I received an absentee ballot but did not return it?

Tags: united-states, election, voting

I signed up to receive a absentee ballots near the beginning of the year. You have the choice to receive them for one election date or all dates that year, and I selected all dates.

I've since moved and I unfortunately didn't think to correct that original address. So, I have not received the absentee ballot.

I'm curious if I can go and vote in person despite the absentee ballot having been sent. Through their online tool I can see if it was returned or not, so I'm assuming the polling place can see that as well?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you registered to vote at your new address?  I don't know Oklahoma law, but in states I am familiar with there is a deadline for registering.  If you missed the deadline, you may be able to vote by affidavit.  But I certainly do not know whether the outstanding absentee ballot has any effect on your ability to vote in person.  Also, since the absentee ballot application must [note the address where you're registered](https://www.ok.gov/elections/Voter_Info/Absentee_Voting/), the absentee ballot may be void anyway because of your move.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but there should be people at your polling location who can help you vote, possibly casting a provisional ballot.  Explain your situation (that you have *not* mailed in your absentee ballot because it was sent to a previous address) and bring proof of address and identity.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like maybe the best course of action at this point is to show up at the polling location and just see what they say.

Comment: In my answer, I recommend contacting your County Elections office, not just going to the polling station. They will be more likely to be able to help you, if you can be helped, than a polling station volunteer.

Comment: For anyone curious, I was able to vote. If you ask for an absentee ballot your registration will be marked at the polls. They'll then have you sign a piece of paper that says "Yes I asked for an absentee ballot, but I did not send it in."

You can then vote as normal. They'll check to make sure you did not cast two ballots afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to vote, since the only prohibitions are on **CASTING** more than one vote, but moving does seem to be more problematic.

There is no cutoff date for updating your address, but you can't cast a vote unless your voter ID card or other documented information matches the name and address on their registration database, and I don't see anything on the site that allows for at the polling location updates or registration.

> **Changing Your Registration**
>
> If you need to change your name, your address or your political affiliation, you must fill out another voter registration application form, or you can update your voter registration information online. You may change your registration at any time with one exception. You may not change your political affiliation during the period from April 1 through August 31, inclusive, in any even-numbered year. The last day on which you may change your political affiliation before the closed period is March 31; the first day on which you may change your political affiliation after the closed period is September 1.
>
> **Voter Identification Card**
>
> You do not become a registered voter until the county election board in the county where you reside has approved your application. When your application is approved, the county election board will mail a voter identification card to you. Your voter identification card lists your name, address, political affiliation and the polling place for your voting precinct. When you receive your voter identification card, look at it carefully and report any errors to the county election board immediately. Keep your voter identification card in a safe place and always take it with you when you go to vote.
>
> If your voter registration application cannot be approved, you will receive a letter from the county election board. The letter will tell you why your application was not approved and explain the steps you need to take to become registered. You may be able to return the letter with some additional information, or you may need to fill out and send in another voter registration application form.

[Oklahoma Elections: Voter Registration in Oklahoma](https://www.ok.gov/elections/Voter_Info/Register_to_Vote/)

You should contact your County elections office to see if you can come in personally and get your address updated on their database, and then ask how you can vote, since the rolls at the polling station won't have you on them.  It will probably be a provisional ballot, if you are able to do this, which is not certain.